# NullPointerException while generating web service with Apache CXF

Tags: java, web-services, nullpointerexception, cxf

I want to create a web service and using Apache CXF 2.7.12. My jdk version is 1.8.0_20. While generating WSDL file in eclipse got this exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.cxf.common.util.Compiler.useJava6Compiler(Compiler.java:187)
at org.apache.cxf.common.util.Compiler.compileFiles(Compiler.java:141)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.generator.wsdl11.BeanGenerator.generateAndCompile(BeanGenerator.java:91)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.generator.wsdl11.BeanGenerator.generate(BeanGenerator.java:58)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.generator.wsdl11.BeanGenerator.generate(BeanGenerator.java:35)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.processor.JavaToWSDLProcessor.generate(JavaToWSDLProcessor.java:156)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.processor.JavaToWSDLProcessor.process(JavaToWSDLProcessor.java:118)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWSContainer.processWSDL(JavaToWSContainer.java:110)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWSContainer.execute(JavaToWSContainer.java:75)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:58)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:40)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWS.run(JavaToWS.java:77)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWS.main(JavaToWS.java:45)
```

I have no idea about the problem related with Java6Compiler.

Comment: what's your eclipse compile settings?  is eclipse set to use 1.8?

Comment: Yes 1.8 I have already only installed jdk 1.8. And set it to environment variables.

Comment: Also add it to the JDK compliance settings in your eclipse. Java Compiler in your properties...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved problem after selecting JavaSE-1.8 execution environment in eclipse. It shows compatible jars 
jre1.8.0_20[perfect match]