# NullPointerException when generating webservice with Apache CXF in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, web-services, cxf

I am following this tutorial to create a web service in a Java web project: https://angelozerr.wordpress.com/2011/08/24/jaxwscxf_step2/. When I get to actually generating it with Apache CXF, it makes all the files and packages (makes two jaxws packages for some reason), but I see this error in the console:

```
java2ws -cp C:\Users\mo\Documents\Workspace\NpcWS\build\classes -s C:\Users\mo\Documents\Workspace\NpcWS\.cxftmp/src -d C:\Users\mo\Documents\Workspace\NpcWS\.cxftmp/wsdl -classdir C:\Users\mo\Documents\Workspace\NpcWS\build\classes -o helloserviceimpl.wsdl -createxsdimports -verbose -frontend jaxws -databinding jaxb -wsdl -wrapperbean org.cloudlet.ws.HelloServiceImpl
java2ws - Apache CXF 3.1.6

May 26, 2016 9:18:55 AM org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromClass
INFO: Creating Service {http://ws.clodulet.org/}HelloServiceImplService from class org.clodulet.ws.HelloServiceImpl
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.Compiler.useJava6Compiler(Compiler.java:187)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.Compiler.compileFiles(Compiler.java:141)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.generator.wsdl11.BeanGenerator.generateAndCompile(BeanGenerator.java:91)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.generator.wsdl11.BeanGenerator.generate(BeanGenerator.java:58)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.generator.wsdl11.BeanGenerator.generate(BeanGenerator.java:35)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.processor.JavaToWSDLProcessor.generate(JavaToWSDLProcessor.java:156)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.processor.JavaToWSDLProcessor.process(JavaToWSDLProcessor.java:118)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWSContainer.processWSDL(JavaToWSContainer.java:110)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWSContainer.execute(JavaToWSContainer.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:58)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:40)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWS.run(JavaToWS.java:77)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWS.main(JavaToWS.java:45)
```

I was reading this: [NullPointerException while generating web service with Apache CXF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034338/nullpointerexception-while-generating-web-service-with-apache-cxf), but my execution environment is already 1.8.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Java class

```
package org.clodulet.ws;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://ws.clodulet.org/", portName = "HelloServiceImplPort", serviceName = "HelloServiceImplService")
public class HelloServiceImpl 
{
    public String getVersion() {
        return "1.0";
    }

    public String hello(String str) {
        return "Hello " + str;
    }
}
```

These are the files it creates: (then the error shows up)

[image]

Comment: Please provide the code for Java2ws class  for better understanding this.

Comment: I just added it to the OP.

Comment: Ok I am analysing the complete program now since the code looks ok to me.

Comment: Thanks! I added the directory structure as well, if it might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the exception trace,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.Compiler.useJava6Compiler(Compiler.java:187)
```

and part of the [Compiler](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cxf/cxf-common-utilities/2.5.11/org/apache/cxf/common/util/Compiler.java#Compiler.useJava6Compiler%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) class

```
180        Object compiler = Class.forName("javax.tools.ToolProvider")
181            .getMethod("getSystemJavaCompiler").invoke(null);
```

seems like you need the Java Compiler, not the Java Runtime, try running it with JDK not JRE.

If you are running java2ws from command line, ensure that your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is pointing to the recently installed JDK folder, if you are using the CXF eclipse plugin you may also need to downgrade to Apache CXF 2.7.18, because the CXF eclipse plugin does not support 3.x versions.

Comment: How would I configure that on Eclipse? I went to execution environment but I can only select JREs.

Comment: Download and install JDK first, then add your JDK folder in your installed JRE's and select as default.

Comment: I agree you should try it with JDK and not JRE

Comment: It's still not working (same error). I think I did it correctly: http://i.imgur.com/xmCvmKi.png

Comment: Show us your project folder structure, with all expanded.

Comment: Let me know if you want anything else expanded. They are pretty big. Structure: http://i.imgur.com/fGoVKxJ.png

Comment: If you are running java2ws from command line, ensure that you are running it with JDK, uninstall previous JRE and leave the JDK only, or set a the JAVA_HOME environment variable pointing to the recently installed JDK folder, or both.

Comment: The JDK is in my PATH variable as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin`. I'm running all of this through Eclipse following the tutorial linked. I uninstalled the JRE and left the JDK only as well. However, it's still not working.

Comment: I added what Eclipse runs inside error portion of the OP. (1st line)

Comment: Add the JAVA_HOME environment variable pointing to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91

Comment: So even after adding it to JAVA_HOME, it still didn't work. I got it to work by using Apache CXF version 2.7. I'm not sure why 3.1.6 or 3.0.9 are giving the exception. However, I still needed to use the JDK instead of the JRE. If you want, you can add the lower version as part of the solution to your post or I can post an answer. Thank you very much for the help!